# Geocoding with contact information

Tags: geocoding, mapquest

I'm looking for some free geocoding service with possibility to retrieve contact information to specific place like phone number, email etc.

Currently I'm using MapQuest:
http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/
and they are returning only localization and name

Comment: sounds like you need google places api (returns location, phone, reviews) https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details but this has to be used within the terms and conditions  https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Comment: I'm implementing turn by turn application and it violates license of Google Maps and probably Google Places, do you know any free solutions or alternatives for commercial use?